# Can't access default Drupal twig functions

Tags: 8, theming

I am unable to get a result back from app.request.attributes.get('_route'). What could cause this. I have tried similar variable and still get no response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Drupal's granular caching, it is not possible to make the global request object available in templates (at least by default); if a template was used on multiple pages, it would be cached with the data from one page and have incorrect information on any others.

If you require the request information in a particular template, you will need to add a preprocess hook to add the additional variable, and ensure that you add the correct cache tags.

To see what variables are available within a particular template, use `{{ dump() }}`